# Partition with cyclic padding

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

The difference between case 1 and case 2 is that the list being partitioned has `5` elements vs `4` elements, respectively.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 3, 1, {3, 1}, {x, y}]
```

> {{x, y, a}, {y, a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, e}, {d, e, y}, {e,
> y, x}}

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d}, 3, 1, {3, 1}, {x, y}]
```

> {{x, y, a}, {y, a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, x}, {d, x, y}}

**Question**

Why is the cyclic padding different at the tail end of the output list for the two cases? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Similar to [255119](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255119/understanding-partition) that I just discovered.

Comment: Somewhat similar [50877](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50877/is-this-the-expected-behaviour-from-partition-when-padding-is-inserted-at-the-st).

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding `Partition` constructs an underlying list of repeating sublists of `{x,y}` which's parts are used to fill in for padding. This I gleaned from this example in the documentation:

https://wolfram.com/xid/0bn6cgi-da1

Let's take an example and mark those positions that will get replaced with `"?"`:

```
Partition[{a, b,c,d}, 3, 1, {3, 1}, "?"]
```

> {{"?", "?", a}, {"?", a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, "?"}, {d,
> "?", "?"}}

When we construct the corresponding "fill-in"-list with repeating units of `{x,y}` it will look like this:

```
Partition[{x, y}, 3, 1, {5, 1}]
```

> {{x, y, x}, {y, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, y}}

Putting the "fill in"-list below the desired output of `Partition` one can easily see where `x` and `y` are replacing the corresponding `"?"`:

> {{"?", "?", a}, {"?", a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, "?"}, {d,
> "?", "?"}}

> {{x, y, x}, {y, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, y}}

Which would match your output from above.

The same happens for your other example. Replace `{x,y}` with `"?"` and have a look:

```
Partition[{a, b, c, d, e}, 3, 1, {3, 1}, "?"]
```

> {{"?", "?", a}, {"?", a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, e}, {d, e,
> "?"}, {e, "?", "?"}}

Compare it with the corresponding "fill-in"-list:

> {{"?", "?", a}, {"?", a, b}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, d, e}, {d, e,
> "?"}, {e, "?", "?"}}

> {{x, y, x}, {y, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, y}, {x, y, x}, {y, x, y},{x, y, x}}

Here you can see that the parts of the "fill-in"-list are `y` and `y,x` for filling the last two sublists in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it very much. I can't phrase my lack of understanding clearly yet but roughly: Does the padlist always start at the first element such as `x` and then the padlist is repeated to create the fill-in list, no matter what the location kL is? Please allow me to study and experiment with it further.

Comment: @Syed You can check out the tutorial on `Partition` here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingLists.html#14460 While I do believe to understand why the padding at the end of the list looks the way it does, I do not yet quite grasp why the beginning is doing what it's doing. I'd need to experiment myself and wrap my head around this.